# Presistent socket in background (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, bonjour

UPDATE: I mean when the application has gone to background, the user closed it, iPhone is on the Springboard. Can be the connection kept alive?

---

I want to push some content to the clients.
Is it possible?
Do I have to register some... ...thing?

Comment: I think you need to add some more detail on what you want to achieve and what you already tried.

Comment: Bonjour is just a service discovery protocol - what is it that you're *really* trying to do ?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970651/is-a-bonjour-connection-notifiy-app-in-background-on-received-data-ios

Comment: The duplicate question has no answer.

Comment: Bonjour is not a "connection". I suggest you research [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) and then ask specific questions relating to that.

Comment: @CocoaDev: That's irrelevant, it's the fact that the OP posted two nearly equal questions that's relevant here.

Comment: Updated the question. Any answer regarding to the question?

Comment: Edited. I have an NSNetService connection resolved, and I want it to be responsive even if the device gone sleep.

Comment: @Emil: I'm ready to send a third question, If no answers came. I think it is not a question that has no answer.

Comment: @Geri: If you do that you will most likely be banned. I suggest you read the FAQ.

Comment: @Emil: I've edited the question, and answered, too.

Comment: @Geri - Posting many duplicates will not get you a better answer (it will get you blocked from asking after enough downvotes though...).  You should be improving your question, not creating another duplicate - edited questions are bumped on the tag/home pages, they get fresh eyes on them as a result.

Comment: @Emil: Ye, as it always turns out, if no answer came, the question is bad (or call it uninformed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register the app as a VoIP app, then a socket will be mantained in the background.

Page 60, and Page 180:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf

The actual background task can be subject of App rejection, you have to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

This should be a good start.

You can keep the connection alive for upto 10 minutes

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier myLongTask;
myLongTask = [[UIApplicationsharedApplication]
          beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
              // If you're worried about exceeding 10 minutes, handle it here
          }];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:myLongTask];
```

This will give you 10 minutes to check for a connection. After 8 minutes, you can use a local Push notification asking the user to open the app to extend it for another 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, 10 minutes and no more?

Comment: Can I "renew" the 10 minute if expired?

Comment: Yes if the app is reopened. This is Apple's rule

Comment: Hope I don't have to setup remote push notifications to keep alive a connection between Local WiFi neighbouring devices.